# NSNumber conversion in Textfield crashes

Tags: swiftui, nsnumberformatter

*I went through old questions but couldn't find a solution for this:*

I have this simple View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var myInt: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Int", value: $myInt, formatter: NumberFormatter())
    }
}
```

In runtime, entering '1111111111111111111', or any 20 digits or more into the TextField crashes with:

> "Fatal error: Unable to bridge NSNumber to Int: file"

If I change the type to:

```
@State var myInt: NSNumber = 0
```

the entered value is converted to '111111111111111110000' and it's not crashing.

**My problem is, I want myInt to be of type Int, not NSNumber, while staying safe from crashing.**

I made several attempts to convert String to NSNumber to Int but nothing worked.

**Attempt 1: Using a Binding, validating in the setter**

```
var body: some View {
        TextField("Int", value: Binding(
            get: { myInt },
            set: {
                var fixedInt: Int
                if $0 > 9223372036854775807 { fixedInt = 0 } else { fixedInt = $0 }
                myInt = fixedInt }
        ), formatter: NumberFormatter())
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: The highest signed value `Int(64)` can hold  is 9223372036854775807, a 20 digit number exceeds that limit.

Comment: yes, sure, but how do I prevent that a too large value is entered? Is the a way to tell Textfield/Numberformatter what to do with a too high value?

Comment: You could add a custom Binding and in the setter check for the overflow before assigning the new value

Comment: I tried that. I updated my question with my Binding code. It has the same problem, it's crashing.

Comment: That’s because the conversion from string to int is done before your Binding code. The check for > 0 in that code is redundant btw, maybe you meant to check for a negative value…

Comment: Thanks Joakim! My check was more coming from the purpose it will have in my app. I changed it now in my question to limit at 9223372036854775807 to have the problem isolated. If you say: "the conversion from string to int is done before your Binding code", where is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments and which led me to focussing better on my question, I found a solution.

First, I finally understood how to access NumberFormatter properties. It wasn't clear to me. I can set them in init():

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var myInt: Int = 0
    
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    
    init() {
        formatter.maximum = 9223372036854775807
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Int", value: $myInt, formatter: formatter)
    }
}
```

To my surprise, it is still possible to crash with giving the values 9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775809. It is not entirely satisfactory in theory, but practically, the values my app will be using are lower, so I can set:

```
formatter.maximum = 922337203685477580
```

or less, of course.